Vue router gives a warning when adding dynamic route: No match found for location with path "/test"
I add a route dynamically and it works but I get the warning below.
"No match found for location with path "/test".
Code Sandbox demo url.
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/eguvenc/routertest/v1.x
main.js
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import TestView from './views/TestView.vue'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)

router.addRoute(
    {
      path: '/test', component: TestView
    }
)

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  console.error(to);
  next();
  if (to.matched.length == 0) {
    // router.push({ path: to.fullPath })
    // we could also use this.$route or useRoute()
    router.replace(to.fullPath)
  }
})

app.mount('#app')

App.vue
<nav>
  <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
  <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
  <a href="/test"><b>Test Dynmaic Route</b></a>
</nav>



use <RouterLink> instead of <a>, not only is it going to avoid the warning, but it reactively updates the page instead of hard reloads.

@yoduh That's valid but unrelated remark. The problem occurs any way when /test url is initially navigated. I suspect that  was used to demonstrate this in a sandbox

The problem is the navigation in Vue router starts at a different time from the rest of the application and can end at different time too, this is the reason for router.isReady method to exist.
It specifically starts at the time when router plugin is registered, not when the app is mounted. If initial navigation relies on dynamic routes, they should be registered before the plugin, so should router hooks:
router.addRoute(...)

router.beforeEach(...)

app.use(router)

The problem could be avoided by moving all router-related logic to router module, so there would be no possibility for race conditions in main module.

After this @Estus Flask's answer I realized there is no need to use beforeEach function. So the final code:
router.addRoute(
    {
      path: '/test', component: TestView
    }
)
app.use(router)

